# Why did Anakin keep his eye scar when Luke got completely healed of much deeper scars from the Wampa?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

Now, I know that the Wampa scene was apparently introduced to account for Hamill's changed nose from his recent car accident but it does seem possible that after the Bacta tank treatment and some other Medical Droid attention, he was completely healed of them, then why isn't this the case with Anakin? Did he just think that the scar looked cool and leave it there?

[image]

[image]

Edit: Apparently the wampa scene was written [even before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106279/was-star-wars-changed-because-of-a-car-crash?) the accident, so it really is possible to heal very deep scars in the galaxy far, far away, which makes me wonder why Anakin (and then Vader) still had theirs.

Comment: For the same reason as [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7483/why-are-anakin-and-luke-fitted-with-cybernetic-hands?rq=1) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7482/why-is-lukes-cybernetic-hand-superior-to-the-one-anakin-receives)?

Comment: Also Darth Vader has much more [extensive scarring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12677/what-is-the-origin-of-darth-vaders-face-scar) than here.

Comment: It just ocurred to me that maybe Anakin being a Jedi at that point was the biggest reason, to heal scars would be to be vain and to want to preserve one's looks, Luke wasn't a fully fledged Jedi when he got scarred so he obviously had no issue with healing his face.

Comment: Also, because he's a schmuck.

Comment: Because chicks dig scars.

Comment: I agree with Gallifreian with respect to Vader's scarring. It was *much* less superficial; probably total destruction of the dermis and even underlying structures. The bacta tank can only do so much. Indeed, it seems from Rogue One that he needs regular bacta treatments just to stay functional.

Comment: As for Anakin, who can say? Maybe he just didn't care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The film's official novelisation indicates that he may have intentionally kept it in order to provide himself with a constant reminder not to become complacent.

> *She reached up to the burn-scar high on his cheek. “You were hurt...”*
>
> *“Nothing serious,” he said with half a smile. “Just an unfriendly
> reminder to keep up with my lightsaber practice.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: [In Legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Even_Piell/Legends#Jedi_Master), Jedi Master Even Piell also kept his one eye for a similar reason as a reminder.

Answer (score -3):

Anakin's scar was inflicted by Asajj Ventress' lightsaber, so maybe lightsaber scars can't be healed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This seems very speculative; do you have any evidence that lightsaber wounds are special?